# How do I import minidv video to windows?

Tags: video, video-editor, video-capture, videotape, mini-dv

I've connected my camcorder to the pc via firewall,driver was also installed but when I plug in and out nothing happen. (Except the sound). Do i need any software?

Comment: What model camcorder? Did you check the manual for instructions on importing?

Answer (score 0):

of course you need software. There are several that give you 30 day trial. or you can install Ubuntu and then download the video with dvgrab. works very well.

Answer (score 0):

DVIO, https://www.videohelp.com/software/DVIO, will capture from the camera into a raw AVI file. No re-encoding, the file contains a perfect digital copy of the data from the tape. Last time I used it was on Windows XP machines, not sure about the current compatibility - but it's worth a try. The download is small, and it's free.

Otherwise, as Stephen suggests, try a trial version of one of the commercial products. Adobe OnLocation also always did a good job of this, but I've not used that in a while either, I just haven't been using MiniDV tapes.

Once you have the tapes digitally downloaded into files, you can re-encode with something like Handbrake, if you want some smaller files that you can use for viewing. I would just keep/archive the original tape download files in case you ever need to go back to the originals.